# Tracking Release Calibration Changes

Tags: svn, version-control

We use a SVN repository to track all of our changes in an embedded system. We have a commonly used release that we send to multiple customers, but each one has a slightly differently calibration.  The source code other than a few variable definitions is the same.

Is there a good way to track all the various calibrations that we release? It gets messy and confusing upping the version number just to tag something with no real effect on the source.  Maybe this should be handled with a separate repository?  Or maybe there is a feature in SVN I am not aware of...

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you can|have to

- Set up (internal for team) naming convention to customer's releases
- Create tag for each "release" using naming scheme from p.1 (i.e. a) edit data-files for *this customer* in trunk, b) commit, c) tag, d) build release from tag with adding REVNO in *some file(s)*... repeat a-d steps for next etc.)

PS - revision-number in data files can be (will be) used later, when customer reports about problem with your product and you have information about **when in happened**